# What does the line "I know every reason why" mean in "Wild and Wicked World"?

Tags: song-lyrics, hayley-kiyoko

In Hayley Kiyoko's song "[Wild and Wicked World](https://genius.com/Hayley-kiyoko-wild-and-wicked-world-lyrics)", the second verse goes like this:

> Take me to the moon
> Where I can sleep 'til noon
> Living my today
> I don't care what you say
> I scream and shout, they shun me out
> And I'm trying hard to make it count
> I get by, I can't deny
> I know every single reason why

I'm not sure what the last line is supposed to mean. It doesn't seem (to me) to be related to any of the previous lines, and immediately after is the chorus, which... doesn't exactly explain what she know every single reason why *what*. Every single reason why... what?

Comment: "the second verse" -> "the second stanza"?